# AspNet EF referencing foreign key to field

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Im having two models:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int ParentNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Batch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string ArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public string ArticleDescription { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public DateTime ProductionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime BestBeforeDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedDateTime { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

One batch can have a customer attached to it. But since we're importing the data from another system we decided not to take over their `id's`. 
Right now the foreign key says try to find a customer by the property `Customer.Id`

I'm trying to achieve to get the foreign key point to `Customer.Number` from `Batch.Customer(Id)`

How would i succeed in this?
I've tried by defining the Customer.Number to be a Key with the Key attribute.. but this made the primary key go from Id to Number which is not what i wanted...

Comment: EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: I'm using EF Core

Comment: And `Batch.CustomerId` property should relate to `Customer.Number`?

Comment: Your foreign keys should always reference primary keys. That's the purpose of a primary key, providing a unique identifier to a particular row. If you want `Number` to be that unique identifier, it should be your primary key.

Comment: @ChrisPratt This was true for EF6. EF Core provides additional options (see my answer).

Comment: No, it's true always. My comment was intentionally general. I'm pretty sure lesser versions of EF supported using a different property as well, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea or that you should. There's simply no good reason to create a foreign key to anything but a primary key, and if you think there's a better column to use, then that's an argument for that column being your primary key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you asking was impossible in EF prior to EF Core. Fortunately in EF Core it can be done by using [Alternate Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/alternate-keys) feature. But please note that in order to be able to use it, your `Cusomer.Number` field should be unique.

The solution requires Fluent API configuration.

Start by defining `Customer.Number` as alternate key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasAlternateKey(e => e.Number);
```

Then set up the relationship as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Batch>()
    .HasOne(e => e.Customer)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustomerId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(e => e.Number);
```

The last two lines will do what you are seeking for.

As a side note, it would be better to name the property (and column) `CustomerNumber` in order to avoid confusion of what the value is in it.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. I already figured it out myself i used the modelbuilder as suggested. But didnt define `HasAlternateKey` this is my modelbuilder:

    `builder.Entity<Batch>()
                   .HasOne<Customer>()
                   .WithMany()
                   .HasPrincipalKey(k => k.Number)
                   .HasForeignKey(k => k.CustomerId)
                   .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`

Comment: Yeah, looks like when you specify `HasPrincipalKey`, it actually creates alternate key for you (both produce unique index on `Number` column).